# Visual Basic 2010 Application with SQL Server CE, database not accessible on Windows XP

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp, sql-server-ce

I was developing an Application that requires a database to store and retrieve data. I am developing the applcation on Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition and using SQL Server Compact Edition for database, on a Windows 7 PC. The Application works perfectly on Windows 7 on my PC. The problem arises on the system of my client who is using Windows XP.

I asked him to install .NET Framework 4.0 and SQL Server CE and send him a copy of the build Application. But when he executed the application and reached a form where database was being used, he encountered and error saying "Access to the database file is not allowed. [ File name = D:\prototype\app\master.sdf ]" and on clicking on continue the form loads but data from the database is not loaded, since it's not connected.

The same problem occurs on windows 7 if i copy the app folder to Program Files directory on Windows 7. But It doesnt occur if i execute the application as "Run as Administrator"

So I require your help to figure out what might be going on and why can't the application access the database simply as it is working on windows 7 (except in the program files directory).

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards

Comment: The user need read-write access to the database file, so you must put it in an suitable location, and change your connection string accordingly. See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: Hi Erik, I am so much thankful to you, you sorted out my problem. Now my application is using the private copy of the sqlce present in the app's folder. Thank you so much!! your blog is a very rich and valuable resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The user need read-write access to the database file, so you must put it in an suitable location, and change your connection string accordingly."
http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

By [EricEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej)